# How to put images on multiple canvases?

Tags: python, image, canvas, tkinter

I have written what should be a simple code to have two canvases in Python/Tkinter both having an image. It always fails on the second canvas saying the image does not exist.

I have tried starting with the other canvas and the image works fine on that, but when calling the canvas that previously worked, it again fails.

Also I tried defining the image out of the subroutine and making it global. did not help

```
from tkinter import *
def canvas1():
    global root,root2,w,photo2,photo1
    root=Tk()
    Button(root,text="new1",command=canvas2).grid()
    photo1 = PhotoImage(file="person.png")
    photo2 = PhotoImage(file="person2.png")
    w=Label(root,image=photo1)
    w.photo = photo1
    w.grid(column=3,row=1)
    root.mainloop()

def canvas2():
    global root,root2,x,photo2,photo1
    root2=Tk()
    Button(root2,text="new2",command=canvas1).grid()
    photo1 = PhotoImage(file="person.png")
    photo2 = PhotoImage(file="person2.png")   
    x=Label(root2,image=photo2)
    x.photo = photo2
    x.grid(column=3,row=1)

    root2.mainloop()

canvas1()
```

I should just have a canvas that calls another with an image on both
I know the image files are okay as they work fine when that canvas is called first.

Comment: Replace `Tk()` on  `root` and `root2` with `Toplevel()` as you shouldn't use more than one main window as `Tk()` all the secondary windows have to be `Toplevel()`. Also you don't need two `mainloop()` one is sufficient. You have the same problem as this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55912283/trying-to-add-an-image-that-functions-like-a-button-but-this-error-image-pyim/55915321#55915321)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to add an image that functions like a button, but this error, image "pyimage2" doesn't exist, pops up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55912283/trying-to-add-an-image-that-functions-like-a-button-but-this-error-image-pyim)